# Should endpoints that represent collections return 404 when no children?

Tags: api, rest, architecture

I have a REST based API where a `gadget` has `widget`s associated with it.

- `gadget`: `/api/gadget/123`
- `widget`s: `/api/gadget/123/widgets`.

The question is what should happen if there is currently no `widget`s for a specific `gadget`?  One interpretation is to return a status code of `404`, the other is to return `200` with an empty list.

Is there a better way? Or is there minutia to the question that we are missing that would help sway one versus the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does seem open to interpretation to me. I would decide based on this - should you expect a `gadget` to always have a collection of `widget`s (even if empty)? If so, I'd go with the `200` response and an empty list, otherwise a `404` requiring some kind of `PUT` or `POST` to initialise the collection.

Put another way, if your resources were to contain links to other resources, should your `gadget` resource always have a link to related `widget`s, which if so may be empty?